# Maximum views in php (videos)

Tags: php, sql, video, max

I want to view the video with maximum views, it is reading the maximum value for example "15" but it doesn't read the video file itself, it keeps reading the first video in the directory.

This is my code:

```
include "mysqli_connect.php";
$db = new Database();
$dbc = $db->getConnection();

$q="select videoFile, min(views) from videos";
$r = mysqli_query($dbc, $q);
echo "<br>$q<br>";

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($r)){
    $views = $row[1];


    $videoFile=$row[0]; 
    echo "<br>$views";
    echo "<br>$videoFile";

    echo "<embed src='http://localhost/VideoProject/Videos/$videoFile' width='550 height='315'></embed>";

}
```

Comment: Your variable `$videoFile=$row[0];` is always assigned to the first index in the returned array.

Answer (score 0):

I don't suggest using numerical indexes if you don't have to, as in this case, they can be unpredictable.   Instead, use the column names from your database, like this...

```
$videoFile = $row['videoFile'];
$views = $row['views'];
```

Also, you say you want the ONE entry with MOST views, so I believe you want...

```
 $q="select videoFile, views from videos ORDER BY views DESC LIMIT 1";
```

Comment: Thank you, this really helped me